# What is the term for "to asynchronously return"?

Tags: promise, future

Many programming languages have the concept of asynchronous functions. The return value of an async function is not the required type itself, but a promise/future that will eventually contain the value.

I'm doing technical writing and I'm struggling to come up with a succinct term for the act of asynchronously returning a value. Consider the following synchronous function:

```
function foo(): boolean { ... }
```

Here, I'd write *"If `foo` returns `true`, ..."* This is perfectly understandable.

Now consider this *asynchronous* function:

```
function bar(): Promise<boolean> { ... }
```

I could write: *"If `bar` returns a promise that resolves to `true`, ..."* This is technically correct, but rather awkward, especially if used repeatedly.

I could write: *"If `bar` asynchronously returns `true`, ..."* This is shorter, but I'm not quite happy with it. To me, it puts the emphasis on "asynchronously", not on "`true`".

I could write: *"If `bar` returns `true`, ..."* This is short, but not technically correct.

I would like to write something like: *"If `bar` yields `true`, ..."*, but the verb to yield already has a different meaning in the context of iterables (at least in some languages).

**Is there a succinct way of expressing this concept?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *yield* (or it synonym *produce*) are totally fine. It should be clear from the context that a promise is meant. When it is not clear, I would use the long and technically precise version (*returns a promise that fulfills with*).

Another option would be *when `bar()` resolves to `true`*, omitting the implicit "the promise returned by the call" but using `bar()` instead of `bar` to refer to the result of the call, not the function itself (which is not a promise that can resolve).

Comment: Thank you for all the great options! For parameterless functions like my example, I like your suggestion of *`bar()` resolves to*. For the general case, I've settled on *`bar` produces*. It's clear and can't be confused with coroutines.